# Change multi select custom field to single select?

Tags: custom-fields, 4.7

We need to convert a multi select box to single select, and the option for doing this in the Change Field Form window looks scary.

> Warning: This functionality is currently in beta stage. Consider backing up your database before using it. Click "Cancel" to return to the "edit custom field" form without making changes.

The option most suitable appears to be "Radio (not safe)". What does "not safe" mean? This field is a crucial element of our membership system and can't be at risk.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what would happen if the field contains multiple values.

What I would do if I where you is the following:

- Create a new field, exactly as you want.
- Export your contacts with only 2 fields: internal id, and the multi-select field
- Check the export and fix the records with multiple values
- Import again, but then use the new field via import mapping
- Check your data
- Disable old field (disabling means you can enable again when needed)
- After a few months and no need to see the old field -> Delete old field

Comment: So you are saying to use an Import Mapping? Map the old field to the new one? I didn't think of that, thanks.